# How can I check hints in Accessibility Inspector?

Tags: ios, xcode, accessibility

I'm wondering if there is a way to check the hints using Accessibility Inspector? Or any other way on iOS to debug the accessibility viewing the hints? Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know, accessibility hints are not displayed in Accessibility Inspector. What I tend to do instead is run the app and then launch layout inspector. After it loads you can select the view you are interested in and see accessibility labels, traits, hints, etc.

I am not sure why hints are not displayed in AI.

Answer (score 0):

By default hints are off in Accessibility inspector, you can turn it on by clicking on "simulator" label present on the top left section of accessibility inspector and then select your app from there. Now it would show hint as well.